# Embedded form - Symfony 4

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony4

Is it possible to create nested form on Symfony 4 without using Entity (Database) ?
I'm actually using API url to get my data. And all the tutorial on internet are using database so ... 
Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You can follow tutorials all the way and omit the parts about **mapping entities** and using **EntityManager** in your controller. Everything else should remain the same. You should create a class representing an entity, use Symfony forms to handle form submissions and **not** persist your entities to the database using entity manager.

**Entity** is just a class used to represent your data. It doesn't necessarily mean that a database is being used.

Comment: @MagicSpells No problem, you can always accept it by clicking the green checkmark if it did in fact help you solve the problem.